# Java NullPointerException on KeyEvent

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am new to Java and this is my first program, except for some 15 line print classes. Every time I try to compile my GameTutorial.java it gets NullPointerException for line 57(inside the update() method). Please, I need help because I don´t know what I am doing wrong. Maybe it is the InputHandler.class, so I wrote it down too.

GameTutorial:

```
import input.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class GameTutorial extends JFrame{

InputHandler input;

public static void main(String[] args){
    GameTutorial game = new GameTutorial(); 
    game.run(); 
    System.exit(0);
};

static int x=10;
static int windowHeight=600;
static int windowWidth=1200;
static BufferedImage backBuffer = new BufferedImage(windowWidth, windowHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

public void run(){
    boolean isRunning = true;

    initialize();

    while(isRunning){
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        update();
        draw();

        time = (1000 / 30) - (System.currentTimeMillis() - time);

        if (time > 0) { 
            try{ 
                Thread.sleep(time); 
            } 
                catch(Exception e){}; 
        };
    };

    setVisible(false);

};

public void initialize(){
    setTitle("Game Tutorial");
    setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
};

public void update(){
    if (input.isKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)){ 
        x += 5; 
    } 

    if (input.isKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)){ 
        x -= 5; 
    }
};

public void draw(){
    Color white = Color.WHITE;
    Color black = Color.BLACK;

    Graphics g = getGraphics(); 

    Graphics bbg = backBuffer.getGraphics(); 

    bbg.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
    bbg.fillRect(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight); 

    bbg.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
    bbg.drawOval(x, 100, 20, 20);

    g.drawImage(backBuffer, 0, 0, this); 
};
```

}

InputHandler:

```
package input;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class InputHandler implements KeyListener{

static boolean[] keys = new boolean[256];

public InputHandler(Component c){
    c.addKeyListener(this);
}

public boolean isKeyDown(int keyCode){
    if (keyCode > 0 && keyCode < 256){
        keys[keyCode]=true;
        return keys[keyCode];
    } 

    return false;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    if (e.getKeyCode() > 0 && e.getKeyCode() < 256){ 
        keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true; 
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){ 
    if (e.getKeyCode() > 0 && e.getKeyCode() < 256){ 
        keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false; 
    }           
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
}
```

Comment: Use the key bindings API over KeyListener and save your self the hassle involved with focus issues and KeyListeners

Comment: What code tutorial are you using?

Comment: This one: http://compsci.ca/v3/viewtopic.php?t=25991

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **input** field never gets a value before been used. You have to initialize it before using its methods.

Something like:

```
input = new InputHandler(whatever);
```

Hope it helps

**Edit**

From your code it will probably be enough replacing the field declaration with a field declaration and initilaization like this:

```
InputHandler input = new InputHandler(this);
```

Comment: Thanks! I really did not know what was going on, you just helped me a lot here!

Answer (score 0):

You did not assign a value to the InputHandler input.

```
input=new InputHandler(argument);
```